# Best Roth IRA stock brokerage account?

Tags: stocks, investing, ira

I'm planning on mainly trading stocks and a few mutual funds in my Roth IRA. I hate paying commission on trades, but I also realize the brokerage has to be reputable/reliable before I invest in it.

The best ones I could find are:

- Fidelity, $4.95 per stock trade, many commision-free mutual funds.
- Chase You
  Invest, $2.95 per stock trade
- Firstrade, $0 per stock trade.

Are there any Others with similar cheap pricing?
Which of the 3 do you recommend the most?

I realize there are others who charge $4.95 per stock trade, but overall Fidelity ranks higher than the competition across the board (at that price). The brokerage should also have a very-low initial deposit.

Comment: Specific brokerage recommendations are considered off-topic here. I think I'm allowed to comment that I've been using Fidelity for years and have been happy with them. If you only invest in index funds, you can avoid commissions altogether.

Comment: That's true. I can use a combination with Fidelity (for index funds), and one of the other cheaper ones for stocks only.

Comment: If you do 'frequent trading' with 'low initial balance', you will soon have _no_ balance left. you can't squeeze much blood from a stone.

Answer (score 2):

Best commission rate depends on what you are trading, the size of your positions, and how you trade (scale in/out or open/close)

If you trade larger blocks of shares, you're better off at a fixed fee broker like Ally, Fidelity or Schwab ($4.95 per trade).

Merrill Edge charges $6.95 per trade but if you maintain a combined balance $50,000 with them and parent company Bank of America, you're eligible for 30 free trades per month ($100,000 gets you up to 100 free trades per month).

RobinHood charges no commission but offers minimal services. If you need more than a stripped down platform, look elsewhere.  Fills may be inferior due to routing for Payment For Order Flow.

Schwab offers 200+ commission free ETFs, nearly 4,000 no load mutual funds and 150+ no transaction fee mutual funds.

For active traders, if you want to scale in and out of positions, Interactive Brokers charges 50 cents per 100 shares ($1 minimum charge per trade). Newer broker tastyworks has competitive commissions but isn't as sophisticated as IBKR, yet.